# Gmail add-ons not available in mobile website?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

This [page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/) states:

> The contextual cards you create for your add-ons work for both web and mobile versions of Gmail. This means that you don't need to create separate web and mobile versions of the add-on — the same code works everywhere!
>
> Note: Gmail add-ons have not yet been added to the iOS version of the Gmail app.

However, if I browse https://mail.google.com from Chrome for Android browser (on mobile phone), I don't see the cards in the mobile website of Gmail, and add-on actions don't seem to work.

Is there a trick to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

By "*mobile version of Gmail*" Google means "**Gmail Application**", as noted in official announcement:

> [..] because add-ons work the same across **web** and **Android**, you only need to install them once [..]

Source: https://blog.google/products/g-suite/do-more-your-inbox-gmail-add-ons/

There is no evidence of Gmail add-ons support by *mobile web* version of Gmail as of May, 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Add-on will get triggered once you open a mail. Scroll down to the end to see the available add-ons in the gmail application.

**Note** Chrome extenstion is not an add-on. It extends the features of google-chrome browser. But a gmail add-on extends the features of gmail itself.

[image: screenshot]